# Angular converting string to date error invalid

Tags: javascript, angular, date

I am getting a date in the form of string date: '2022-07-15T09:29:24.958922Z[GMT]', When I convert it in to date then I get error invalid date. Does someone know how to solve it?

```js
   const myDate = response; // '2022-07-15T09:29:24.958922Z[GMT]'
   this.transactionDate = new Date(myDate);
```

Comment: The '[GMT]' part makes it an invalid date string for javascript.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is [GMT] in your response string.

Either your response should be something like this

```
new Date("Fri Jan 20 2022 11:51:36 GMT-0500")
```

or you need to remove [GMT] from your existing string

```
 var datestring ='2022-07-15T09:29:24.958922Z[GMT]';
 datestring.substr(0,datestring.indexOf('['));
 new Date(datestring)
```

```js
var withGMT = new Date("Fri Jan 22 2022 11:51:36 GMT-0500")
console.log(withGMT);

var dateString ='2022-07-15T09:29:24.958922Z[GMT]';
var withoutGMT=dateString.substr(0,dateString.indexOf('['));
console.log(new Date(withoutGMT))
```

Comment: Using *substr* with *indexOf* means that if the timestamp doesn't have "[GMT]" at the end then the result is *null*. Better to use replace, e.g. `dateString.replace(/\[.+$/,'')`.